# ASP.NET site works through VS, but not through browser

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, wiki

I don't have the code in front of me right now (but will in an hour or so), but suspect that the solution is very simple so I'll post a general description of the problem and update it later:

Problem:

A site built on ASP.NET works fine when browsing it through Visual Studio, but when attempting to connect via browser, it complains about looking for a default page (I can update later with the exact error).

Details:

Our development team is trying to set up a (VERY) simple wiki server for our internal project using SEWEN WIKI, a wiki server based on Wikiplex. None of us are web developers.

I'm 99% positive that it's something as simple as creating a index.html or something as an entry point for the browser, but I'll admit my domain knowledge here is about 0.

IIS has been updated to 7.5 (min required is 7), and ASP.NET has been upgraded past 4 (the required version). The operating system is Windows 2008 Server, and the wiki is developed in Visual Studio 2010.

If anybody has any ideas, I'd love to know. Thanks!

Comment: You have to set up the default page in IIS , it is normal if you're using asp.net to make IIS look for Default.aspx first , it may still be looking for like index.html or something  - Also , this can be a list of files it looks for

Comment: Have you installed the ASP.NET development service, under "Application Development Features" when installing IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have ASP.NET enabled on your server as @Patrick suggests in the comments, it's possible that you need to configure a **Default Document** as @ScottSelby suggests.

Here is documentation on this topic from Microsoft: [Configure the List of Default Documents in IIS 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771439%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

I've illustrated this below:

In the **Features View** of IIS, click **Default Document**:
[image: IIS]

In **Default Document**, ensure that you have your designated page, commonly *default.aspx*:
[image: Default Document]

Comment: Thanks everyone, took me from problem #1 to #2 haha